# ReactJS - ref returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, position, ref

I'm using ReactJS with NextJS. When I'm trying to set a `ref`, my console returns me `undefined`, how it is possible? How remedy to this difficulty? I have tried to read some propositions on the web but without success.

Here my snippet:

```
 componentDidMount() { 
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, { passive: true })
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
      }

      handleScroll(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // let offsetTop = this.myRef.current.offsetTop;

        // here I'm trying just a console.log to preview the value
        // otherwise my program will just crash
        console.log("I'm scrolling, offsetTop: ", this.myRef) 
      }

  render() {
    return (
        <div  className={style.solution_container_layout} >

            <div   ref={this.myRef} className={style.solution_item}>
```

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `current` property of the object returned from `createRef` is set on the first render, so if you create it in the `componentDidMount` after the component has been rendered it will not be set.

You also have to bind the `handleScroll` method, or `this` will not be what you expect.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  myRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll, { passive: true });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = () => {
    console.log("I'm scrolling", this.myRef.current);
  };

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} style={{ height: 1000 }}> Scroll me </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, but seems the relative position of my element to the viewport top - with scrollTop - seems to remain fixed, like there is one measure then no other is done, do you know maybe what happens please

Comment: @Webman Since the element doesn't scroll its `scrollTop` doesn't change. You might want ` window.pageYOffset` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell from the code you added, but you might be simply missing this imperative in your constructor:

```
constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)
}
```

more info: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb